# Why does the leftmost Outlook Calendar act glitch and not scroll properly?

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, microsoft-outlook-2019

I'm having an issue with Outlook Calendars when viewing shared calendars.

Specifically, I'm having trouble with the leftmost calendar not scrolling up and down properly like the right side.

With a mouse, it works properly, this only happens with a TouchPad. When letting go of the TouchPad, the leftmost does snap into place.

This happens on multiple laptops of the same make and model.

Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga G2, Windows 10

Anyone experienced this issue before? Any suggestions on how to fix?